# MQTT Load Testing via Jenkins using JMETER

Tags: github, jenkins, jmeter, maven-3, mqtt

I'm trying to run MQTT test using JMeter on Jenkins. I've integrated maven and used Github repository to run the script. The problem is when i try to run a simple API test, jenkins automatically creates a .jtl file(provided that i've added post build action) In case of MQTT test script, Jenkins Build is successful but the test fails showing this error " no JMeter files matching '*.jtl' have been found.". Why is it so???

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you use Jenkins performance plugin? If not you should do it.
2. Do you run JMeter in the Non GUI mode? If not you have to.
   In this article [how to run JMeter with jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) you'll find step by step guide for Jenkins configuration for launching JMeter tests.

Comment: 1. Yes I'm using the performance plugin.
2. I am running the JMeter script using Maven which runs the script in Headless mode. The link you've given is for API test and as I've mentioned before, API test runs perfectly fine. The issues lies with the MQTT test script.